# setOpaque() method

Tags: java

I would like to know what setOpaque() method do...

here is a part of small program:

```
    public class Buttons extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {

     private JButton button;
     private JLabel label;
     private JTextArea text;
     private String t;
     public Buttons()
     {
      super("TESTING");
      label = new JLabel("Hello!!!!");
      button = new JButton("Color Change");
      text = new JTextArea("Test");
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      label.setOpaque(true);
      add(button);
      add(label);
      add(text);

            LabelHandler labelHandler = new LabelHandler();

      button.addActionListener(this);
            label.addMouseListener(labelHandler);

      setSize(300,200);
      setVisible(true);
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
      if (e.getSource()==button)
      {
       label.setBackground(Color.red);
      }
      if (e.getSource()==text)
      {
       if (t == "\n")
       {
        setText(t);
        label.getText();
       }
      }
     }



    class LabelHandler extends MouseAdapter
    {
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
     {
  label.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
     }
 }
```

Without the setOpaque it wont paint the label. Why?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Opaque means that it isn't transparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The opaque flag is used by the Swing `ComponentUI` to test whether they should paint their background or whether they should not.  If you set your background color, but fail to `setOpaque(true)`, you will not see that bg color.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some info: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/setopaque.html